# How to add firebase database to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I try to make an online store. I did the register/login part using firebase and it works, but when I try to retrieve data from database in another javascript file, I get an error.

The javascript line where I get the error:

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
```

The error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at BooksArtJS.js:17
```

The html code:

```
<script src="BooksArtJS.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-auth.js"> </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "theApiKey",
    authDomain: "theAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "theDatabaseURL",
    projectId: "theProjectID",
    storageBucket: "theStorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "theMessagingSenderID",
    appId: "theAppID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your script with BooksArtJS.js after firebaseConfig script, also, for security reasons it is better to make a new js file called something like "conn.js" and moving your config files there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `BooksArtJS.js` script is using firebase. You should place script after firebase is loaded:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "theApiKey",
    authDomain: "theAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "theDatabaseURL",
    projectId: "theProjectID",
    storageBucket: "theStorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "theMessagingSenderID",
    appId: "theAppID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="BooksArtJS.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you have wrong `"users/"` Look:

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
```

Change it to `"users"`

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
```

Or you can use:

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase version 9.0.2  you can use the code as below.

The HTML code.

```
<script>

    const firebaseApp  = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "theApiKey",
    authDomain: "theAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "theDatabaseURL",
    projectId: "theProjectID",
    storageBucket: "theStorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "theMessagingSenderID",
    appId: "theAppID"
    });

    const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
    const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

</script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
```